# Show the top 5 items in percentage of the total in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Item,Quantity
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
E,5
F,6
G,7
H,8
I,9
J,10

Is there a way to show the top 5 items in percentage of the total in pivot table? When I click 'show top 5', the total changes to the sum of only the 5 items, what I actually want is the sum of all items (i.e. item J will be 18.18% instead of 25%)

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in your source data that calculates the relevant percentage then include that in your PivotTable.

Comment: is it possible to do it within pivot table without changing the original data? because the real dataset is much more complex